# How to write boolean value to Arrow ListVector

Tags: java, apache-arrow

Usually we use UnionListWriter to write to ListVector in Arrow Java API. But I didn't find there is an API like writeBoolean in UnionListWriter. So How can we write Boolean value to a List in Arrow?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a boolean as an integer with 0 standing for false. For a list of booleans, I think the best approach might be to use UnionListWriter#writeBit();

```
  @Override
  public void writeBit(int value) {
    writer.writeBit(value);
    writer.setPosition(writer.idx()+1);
  }
```